# Two (Separate) jQuery Tab Plugins Kill my Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm developing a very large page with lots of content and some overlays and all kinds of complicated things. I'll spare you all the code and only include the relevant pieces.

Essentially, I have some sidebar buttons that open an overlay depending on the button clicked. The HTML is below:

```
<div class="sideBtn sidebarOverlay" data-linkto="overlayMyInvoices">
    <img src="icons/icon_invoice.svg" alt=""><h2>Invoices</h2>
</div>

<div id="overlayMyInvoices" class="overlay">
</div>
```

And here is some of the Javascript:

```
$(sideBtns).click(function(index){

    var newId = "#" + (($(this).data("linkto")).toString());
    var newOverlay = $(newId);

});
```

(I've left out a LOT of the Javascript, as I said I'm only including the relevant bits. That 'toString' might not be necessary, I'm not entirely sure I had it in there looking back, but I very much doubt that's the problem.)

BEFORE adding the jQuery tab plugin, this code works fine.

Now, INSIDE one of these overlays, I need some 'tabbed' content - so I downloaded three separate jQuery tab plugins, and ALL THREE of them produced the same error. In this particular case, the one I'm using is [Tabslet](http://vdw.github.io/Tabslet/). First, here's the HTML of the tab area:

```
<div id="overlayMyInvoices" class="overlay">
    <div class='tabs'>
        <ul class='horizontal'>
            <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id='tab-1'></div>
        <div id='tab-2'></div>
        <div id='tab-3'></div>
    </div><!-- tabs -->
</div>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
$('.tabs').tabslet();
```

For some reason, every single jQuery tab plugin I use produces the same identical error (I've also used jQuery's UI core plugin, and [EasyTabs](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/)). When I try to open ANY overlay using the sidebar buttons, the overlay doesn't appear, and I get THIS console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

Perhaps the oddest element of this error is that it only appears ONCE. Any subsequent clicks after that first error function properly.

I just don't see how these plugins could be causing this error to appear. jQuery was able to read the custom data field before, how come it can't all of a sudden? If I don't call the plugin, it works again.

I realize this is a very long and complicated problem, but if anyone has ideas as to what this problem is and how to fix it, I'd be extremely grateful!

Comment: What is the value of `this` when the error occurs?

Comment: `console.log(this)`  

returns the the div element, just as I'd expect.  

`<div class="sideBtn sidebarOverlay" data-linkto="overlayMyInvoices">...</div>`  

Also worth noting (I'll edit my original post to reflect this): it works the SECOND time I click. But the first click, each time the page loads, returns the error.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem, or link to the actual site?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The project is actually protected by an NDA, I can't post the page in its entirety. These small bits of code are acceptable, but that's all.

Comment: You need to post enough for us to be able to see the error. As is, there's nothing that indicates any relationship between the tabs and the click handler. They don't even use the same selectors.

Comment: You can understand my confusion then! As it stands, all the relevant code has been posted. There's absolutely no reason for either of these things to be related. Most baffling of all is the fact that the error only occurs once - there isn't anything that should dynamically happen in between the first and second clicks that would cause Javascript to fail to read the custom dataset of 'this' the first time but do it successfully the second time.

Comment: We don't need the page in its entirety. If you can whittle it down to a subset that reproduces the problem, with fake data, make a jsfiddle. I don't think there's enough for us to go on here.

Comment: I'll need to wait to talk to the client first. Personally I can't imagine why a whittled-down version wouldn't be acceptable, but, you know, better safe than sued. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem, for anyone who still cares. I wrote some incredibly stupid Javascript that was looking for the class 'active'. Just any element with the non-specific class 'active'. The thing about 'active'? It's a great word that a lot of developers use. My code and the plugins were both using 'active', and my Javascript, since it was just looking for 'active' anywhere on the page, was effing up. So my own fault! Good.